# Rails collection_select text_method to access related value

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

A collection_select is being invoked and renders the slot_id generated from `@day_slots`

```
<%= collection_select(:slot, :id, @day_slots, :slot_id, :slot_id) %>
```

controller

```
@day_slots = @slots.uniq {|p| p.slot_id}
```

However, the desired `text_method`is a related value  `slot.description`

How can that be accessed in the collection_select statement, as it only accepts a symbol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do...

```
<%= collection_select(:slot, :id, @day_slots, :slot_id, :description) %>
```

Which will use the description method of the slot objects as the text method

Comment: description is not a value of a DaySlot class.  That class is actually a join table (has_many through) and I'm attempting to access the related value of the Slot class.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter. As long as `description` method exists and works on the objects in `@day_slots` If your saying the relationship is `day_slot.slot.description` then you can delegate the method

class DaySlot;
  def description;
    slot.description;
  end;
end

Comment: Ah yes... as rails has many hooks into accessing related values, I remained under the assumption that this would be the case as well under collection_select.